# gcov not working with pthreads, WSL-2, Clion

Tags: c++, pthreads, clion, gcov, wsl-2

Background:
This seems to work fine if I don't use any threads or just spawn 1 thread, which makes this all the more confusing.

Clion Project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P0dN89iiP-YQXtXc1mDA5-aGHgGFcLVK/view?usp=sharing)

Problem:
I set up a basic example project that starts 2 threads and does some printing to the console from main thread, thread 2, and thread 3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void thread1()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "thread1" << std::endl;
    }
}

void thread2()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "thread2" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::thread threadObj(thread1);
    std::thread threadObj2(thread2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"MainThread"<<std::endl;
    }
    threadObj.join();
    std::cout<<"Exit of Main function"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling using:

```
--coverage -pthread -g -std=gnu++2a
```

When I run in clion using "Run 'EvalTest' with Coverage", I get the following error:

> Could not find code coverage data

[image]

So it's not producing the gcov files needed, but it works fine if I comment out the following line of code:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::thread threadObj(thread1);
//    std::thread threadObj2(thread2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"MainThread"<<std::endl;
    }
    threadObj.join();
    std::cout<<"Exit of Main function"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ first one is using a service call, which I'm not doing.  I'm just using default threads, so I don't think that applies.  Second one talks about corrupted files, but I'm not getting any gdca or gcov output file at all.

Comment: But isn't the principle the same? This service call is also executed asynchonously for sure (since `boost:asio` is used). You should at least try, if you find a solution based on the OP's answer there. There seem to be problems with `gcov` and producing the correct gcda files, and I can well imagine why is that (the injected code is probably not thread safe). Also try to setup a [mcve] in form of a test project and post it here, such that everyone can try that out.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I will investigate the first comment you posted some more.  As for test project, what do you want me to post here?  The whole clion project?  I guess I can zip up the current project and post here.

Comment: I asked you to separate the specific case out to a new small project. Just a `main()` function, two thread functions and started these from main. Also the whole gcov setup (compiler command line and such) to instrument the thread functions for coverage. This would also help yourself to investigate more about the problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok... let me redo this whole thing.  I thought the current project was simple enough, but I will reduce it as you suggest.

Comment: _"but I will reduce it"_ As mentioned it's probably easier to setup a copmpletely new one. Shouldn't be "rocket science" ;-) Also if you can't reproduce the problem with a new project, that would be a strong indication, that something else is wrong with your actual project, and it's not necessarily about the multithreading in general. Ive been working over years with gcov (couple of years ago), and it has it's shortcomings sometimes. E.g. dealing with header only code (e.g. for templated classes)  it doesn't work that well, unless you provide explicit template specializations in separate cpp's

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry... that's what I meant by reducing.  I created a brand new project.  Will update problem shortly.

Comment: Ok... I figured out the problem. Will create answer.

Comment: Great. I look forward to it. You may ping me, as I am curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to do threadObj.join() and threadObj2.join().  So code looks like:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::thread threadObj(thread1);
    std::thread threadObj2(thread2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"MainThread"<<std::endl;
    }
    threadObj.join();
    threadObj2.join();  // need to join both thread for gcov to work properly
    std::cout<<"Exit of Main function"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ not sure how to ping you except to mention you in a comment.  Here's the answer :)

Comment: This brings up another questions.  Is there no way to collect coverage information if a thread runs forever?